# how to get element by href and add a class to this element

Tags: javascript, typescript, dom

I try to get an element by his href and add a class to this element in typescript,
For this I tried :

```
let path = window.location.pathname;
let link = document.querySelectorAll("a[href="+path+"]");
console.log(link);
```

But my console.log throw me an error

```
querySelectorAll' on 'Document' is not a valid selector
```

Do you know how could I fix this ?
Thanks

Comment: Also querySelectorAll returns a collection. You might want to consider just querySelector

Comment: Are you sure the href will be the path only? Perhaps you meant `document.querySelector(\`a[href*="${path}"]\`);` which see if the href contains the path instead of is equal to the path

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't TypeScript specific. It's just native Javascript :)

You're missing enclosing brackets around your `path` variable.

```
let path = window.location.pathname;
let link = document.querySelectorAll('a[href="'+path+'"]');
console.log(link);
```

Optionally, depending on what browsers you need to support - you can make this code more readable by using interpolation and template literals:

```
let path = window.location.pathname;
let link = document.querySelectorAll(`a[href="${path}"]`);
console.log(link);
```

Comment: You're suggesting I copied and pasted this answer from somewhere because I was too quick? Dude - I'm a full-time web developer. This really wasn't a difficult problem to figure out.

Comment: Ahh - my apologies. Misinterpreted the context of your comment :)
Thanks for updating the second example. You spotted it before I could edit it!